# Limits with complex numbers

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

$$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z^*}{z}$$

The way I see it is that it's asking what happens when $z$ approaches $0$. However, I can't just say undefined because $z$ is actually $z=x+iy$. So if I take the complex conjugate of the bottom I remove the $i$ from the denominator and can get it into standard form. The problem then is what does it mean to say that $z$ goes to $0$ when I have $x, y, i$?

Comment: Does $z^*$ mean conjugate of $z$ ?

Comment: @Freelancer yup

Answer (score 4):

If $z$ is real, then
$$
\frac{\bar z}{z} = \frac{z}{z} = 1
$$
so if the limit exists it must be equal to $1$ (approach $0$ along the real axis). On the other hand, if $z = ib$ is purely imaginary
$$
\frac{\bar z}{z} = \frac{-ib}{ib} = -1
$$
so if the limit exists it must be equal to $-1$ (approach $0$ along the imaginary axis).

There are no numbers that are equal to $1$ and $-1$, so the limit cannot exist.

Comment: Why is the imaginary conjugate negative but the real part isn't?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat Because for real numbers, the conjugate will have the same sign as the given number, ie. the conjugate of 4i is -4i but the conjugate of 4 is not -4, but just 4

Comment: So in my readings I stumbled upon an old gem - L'Hopital's rule. Could that be applied here? Not sure how that would work with a conjugate but it worked on another problem of mine: $\lim_{z\to i} \frac{z-i}{z^4-1}$. I found that the limit is $i$. Could this be somehow applied to $\frac{\bar z}{z}$?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat there is a version of l'Hopital that applies to quotients of holomorphic (complex-differentiable) functions, but $\bar z$  is not differentible in the complex sense, so that wouldn't work here. Your other example is ok, but I would prefer just factoring and cancelling the $z-i$ factor.

Answer (score 1):

Any complex number can be written as $z=re^{i\theta}$ where $r$ and $\theta$ are real numbers.

Another way to say that $z\to 0$ is to say $r\to 0$, regardless of what $\theta$ does.

In your particular case,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{z^*}z &= \frac{re^{-i\theta}}{re^{i\theta}} \\[2ex]
 &= e^{-2i\theta}
\end{align}$$

which does not have $r$ in it at all. The limit depends on just how $z$ approaches zero. By choosing the path to keep a certain angle $\theta$ we can get any value on the  unit circle as the limit. Since the limit depends on the path, there is no overall limit.

Comment: What do you mean by ''the path''?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat: One way to think of a limit of a function of a complex number as $z\to 0$ is to think of $z$ as a moving point on the complex plane, moving closer and closer to the point zero. Point $z$ takes a path to get close to zero. It is often easy to find the limit as $z$ approaches zero along the path. If the limits *of all paths to zero* are equal, this is the overall limit. Otherwise, the overall limit is undefined. In my answer, I consider $z$ moving on a line segment from somewhere straight to the origin, which keeps $\theta$ constant.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat: mrf's answer considered four paths: from $1$ to zero ($\theta=0$) and from $-1$ to zero ($\theta=\pi$), both having the function limit (and constant value) $e^0=e^{2\pi}=1$, and the path from $i$ to zero ($\theta=\pi/2$) and from $-i$ to zero ($\theta=-\pi/2$), both having the function limit (and constant value) $e^{i\pi}=e^{-i\pi}=-1$. So his answer is a subset of my answer, explained somewhat differently.