# How do I evaluate a complex limit involving the conjugate?

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

I know that

$$
\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\bar{z}}{z}
$$

Does not exists because if we consider a $z_0$ as a real number ($z = x$), the limit is 1, and if $z_0$ is a pure imaginary number ($z = iy$), the limit is -1. With that, I can prove that the limit does not exists.

But if I have:

$$
\lim _{z\to 0}\left(\left(\frac{z}{\bar{z}}\right)^2\right)
$$

And do the same tests, I always get the limit equals to one.
Is it correct to say that this limit equals 1 because of the two ways of approaching it gives the same result?

Comment: No it is not enough. There are other ways to approach $0$ than from the $x$ or $y$ axes. Consider $z=r\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\,\theta}$ and thus $\overline z=r\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i\,\theta}$ as $r\to0$, in a fixed “direction” $\theta$.

Comment: No. Theoretically, you could get a different limit while approaching $0$ along a different axis that the two ones you studied.

Comment: I actually found that, if I consider $z = x + ix$ the limits equals to -1, so I think this proves the limits does not exists...

Comment: When we say a complex number $z$ approaching $z_1$ then it is equivalent to $|z - z_1| \to 0$, and we do not care which direction $z$ is approaching $z_1$. The limit exists iff the limit is the same for any direction. Also see this question for more info https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1627863/limits-with-complex-numbers.

Comment: Using polar coordinates, neither $e^{-i\theta}$ nor $e^{i2\theta}$ have a limit.

Comment: With $y=mx$, $\left(\dfrac{1+im}{1-im}\right)^2$ is certainly not a constant function.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If $t>0$ and $z=(1+i)t$, then$$\frac z{\overline z}=\frac{1+i}{1-i}=i,$$and therefore$$\left(\frac z{\overline z}\right)^2=-1.$$So, again, the limit does not exist.